# iOS app isn't opening from facebook messenger. Works in other apps

Tags: ios, facebook, meta-tags, applinks

I'm having issues getting my installed iOS app to open from facebook messenger. It works in other apps such as iMessage, safari, whatsapp etc.It just seems to open in the facebook messenger browser.

I've tried following this sample: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content and setting up app links but it doesnt seem to work.

I've added the meta tags to my app as well.

I've ran the link in the facebook debugger, and it shows the app links are on the page.
App Links

```
al:ios:url  applinks://app
al:ios:app_store_id storeid
al:ios:app_name name
```